# How to fix https certificate issue?

Tags: ssl

How to fix the below ERROR? I must use the certificate. while i use the "https://apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net/exists/myapceratest" in firefox, it is not problem, why does wget get wrong?

apple@apple-Z600:~/virtualbox/apcera$ wget https://apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net/exists/myapceratest
--2016-05-19 04:14:55--  https://apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net/exists/myapceratest
Resolving apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net (apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net)... 54.186.184.30, 52.10.181.83, 54.149.113.218
Connecting to apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net (apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net)|54.186.184.30|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2’:
  Issued certificate has expired.
To connect to apcera-dns.prod.apcera.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Comment: `Issued certificate has expired` says it all. The certificate is out of date.

Comment: How to update the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the Issued certificate has expired.

Comment: @flyxiao The website which issued you with the certificate have to provide you with the procedure on how to renew. if you follow their procedure, you will be issued an encryption key. You may follow this video www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hq5s-tjYeY